CSS linear-easing-function bug
Edit: add full html code


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
      body {
        display: flex;
        width: 100vw;
        height: 100vh;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
      }
      #box {
        width: 400px;
        height: 200px;
        background-color: rgb(255, 93, 93);

        /* work with linear */
        /* transition: transform 0.5s linear(0, 0.5 25%, 1); */

        /* not work with linear */
        transition: transform 0.5s
          linear(
            0,
            0.009,
            0.035 2.1%,
            0.141,
            0.281 6.7%,
            0.723 12.9%,
            0.938 16.7%,
            1.017,
            1.077,
            1.121,
            1.149 24.3%,
            1.159,
            1.163,
            1.161,
            1.154 29.9%,
            1.129 32.8%,
            1.051 39.6%,
            1.017 43.1%,
            0.991,
            0.977 51%,
            0.974 53.8%,
            0.975 57.1%,
            0.997 69.8%,
            1.003 76.9%,
            1.004 83.8%,
            1
          );
      }
      #box:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="box">Hover Me</div>
  </body>
</html>




I set css transiton as
box {
  /* others */

  transition: transform 0.85s
    linear(
      0,
      0.0346 2.07%,
      0.1407 4.43%,
      0.9383 16.72%,
      1.0774 20.43%,
      1.1493 24.31%,
      1.1629 26.95%,
      1.1536 29.93%,
      1.0168 43.09%,
      0.9766 51%,
      1.0033 76.88%,
      1
    );
}

then I get this in browser

But when I set linear in one line,
box {
  /* others */

  transition: transform 0.85s linear(0, 0.0346 2.07%, 1.0033 76.88%, 1);
}

then I get this and it works.

I couldn't use long value linear easing.
To fix this I use emotion, which is CSS-in-JS library, so that I can handle it by setting as string.
--spring-easing: ${`linear(0, 0.0025 1.75%, 0.004 2.29%, 0.0099 3.55%, 0.0197 4.92%, 0.0341 6.4%,
      0.0533 7.84%, 0.0744 9.06%, 0.0738 9.06%, 0.1003 10.32%, 0.1281 11.41%,
      0.1598 12.44%, 0.194 13.37%, 0.231 14.21%, 0.2714 14.97%, 0.3447 16.05%,
      0.344 16.05%, 0.4768 17.47%, 0.5443 18.34%, 0.6069 19.39%, 0.6604 20.61%,
      0.6897 21.46%, 0.7167 22.4%, 0.7419 23.44%, 0.7653 24.59%, 0.7876 25.87%,
      0.8083 27.28%, 0.8272 28.79%, 0.8448 30.42%, 0.8649 32.63%, 0.8656 32.71%,
      0.8645, 0.8656 32.72%, 0.8686 33.08%, 0.8833 35.06%, 0.8888 35.86%, 0.8876,
      0.8888 35.87%, 0.9002 37.72%, 0.9009 37.83%, 0.9001 37.83%, 0.9039 38.37%,
      0.9155 40.62%, 0.9295 43.79%, 0.9421 47.24%, 0.9533 50.97%, 0.9633 54.99%,
      0.972 59.33%, 0.9795 64.01%, 0.9858 69.04%, 0.9909 74.43%, 0.9949 80.2%,
      0.9977 86.37%, 1
    );`};

Is there another way to fix it?
Is this formatter bug?

Can you attach the html, and executable code?

@NINE I added it. please check.

Works fine for me in Firefox. Maybe it’s a Chrome bug. You don’t really need the complicated example, just putting any whitespace directly after linear( will do.

@Ry- I got it. thx. :)
